# How long do I have to accept a dweller into my Vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

You can "collect" dwellers in multiple ways: via Lunchboxes, a Radio Room, or by breeding.

Now, I know that when a woman gets pregnant, she won't deliver the baby unless you choose to.

But what about dwellers from outside the Vault? Do they leave after a certain amount of time? Is it the same for dwellers from Lunchboxes?

What about collecting a call from the Radio Room? If I don't collect the call, will that call vanish after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wasteland Dwellers whom are on the outside of the vault waiting to get inside will stay forever until you accept them in or choose otherwise. Radio calls on the other hand can be accepted at any time just like any other resources (Stimpacks etc.); the downside being that anyone in the room stops gaining experience.

I know this based on my knowledge of the game. Hope it helped.

Comment: And the call won't dissappear if I choose to leave it?

Comment: No, much to my annoyance, it's always there waiting for you to slip and have to deal with another peasant. And the assigned dwellers won't gain any XP.