# Is there a limit for the waiting queue outside the vault?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Inspired by this [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/269315/how-long-do-i-have-to-accept-a-dweller-into-my-vault) i wondered how many Dwellers can wait outside the vault. Even if there is no gameplay limit, what happens when more dwellers are waiting then can be graphically displayed because of limited space?

Imaging scenario, you have sent 25 dwellers for exploring and always accept on radio station or get some from lunchboxes without letting them in the vault. Now the 25 dwellers return but you already have 50+ new dwellers waiting in front of the vault.

What happens? There is no room to display 75+ dwellers outside of the vault (or wathever the limit is how many dwellers can be visible in the queue). Are they only not visible but still waiting outside? Or is there a limit how many new dwellers can wait outside? Has anybody tested this so far?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have 10  dwellers queuing outside my vault that I don't want to let in. I have 25 explorers and 200 dwellers in my vault. I also have two lunchboxes that I can't open "There are too many dwellers in the waiting line".

Comment: So what happens when one of your explorers returns? Are they added to the line or not?

Answer (score 4):

A few versions ago I had 10 dwellers waiting outside my fault, and could not queue the 11th, even though the radio room had "produced" another dweller.

Comment: Sry, I am non native english speaker. Does "topped out" mean you had 10 waiting and did not try further or does it mean after 10 you could not add another to queue? If second, what happened when you got another via lunchbox? Could not find this expression in my online dictionary...

Comment: Edited for clarity. I had 10 waiting and could not acquire an 11th, despite the radio room 'producing' another dweller.

Answer (score 0):

if there's 10 or more people waiting outside for any reason then new dwellers never appear at your door weather it's from lunchboxes, quests, radio rooms, or the 15 or so free dwellers you get at the start of the game, however you can have dwellers return from quests and wasteland exploration come to the que, so the limit of dwellers waiting at the door should be 10 waiting to be let in for the first time + 22 returning from the wasteland + 9 returning from quests for a total of 41